$f, g : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ both measurable. Prove {$x\in E : f(x) \leq g(x)$} is measurable
I've seen this answered in other post, but my question is regarding my approach. Is is enough to say that $ \forall x \in E$ then $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}  $ such that {$x \in E: f(x) \leq g(x)$}$\subseteq$ {a$\leq g$} $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ and as {a$\leq g$} measurable by definition, then  {$x\in E: f(x) \leq g(x)$} also measurable?  or am I missing something and that's why the approach using the intersection of both functions is necessary?
Thanks in advance

I would say NO.  The fact that ${a \le g}$ is measurable  for all constant $a$ does not (by itself) imply ${f \le g}$ is measurable for function $f$.

Thanks for the answer! But what should I add to make the implication? I can't see how being contained in the set of all x such that g is bigger than some number doesn't imply it being measurable

The total set $E$ is measurable, but not all subsets of $E$ are measurable. Therefore, it is not true that the subset of a measurable set is measurable. Also, I do not agree with your claim that ${x \in E : f(x)\leq g(x)} \subseteq {x \in E: a\leq g(x)}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, note that $$f(x)\leq g(x) \iff f(x)-g(x)\leq 0$$
